# setting up key based authentication for windows 10 ssh server and client

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh, public-key-encryption

I am trying to set up public private key authentication for the windows 10 beta openssh server and client. But i am running into the problem where it still asks for a password.

here's what I did.

-client

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
scp "C:\Users\user1\.ssh\id_ed25519.pub" user1@serverip:"C:\Users\user1\.ssh"
ssh-add
```

removed all permissions from the private key file, except for the user who has full control.

-server

created a txt file called authorized_keys, and copied the contents of id_ed25519.pub into it.

But connecting to my server using 
`ssh user1@serverip` or `ssh -i C:\Users\user1\.ssh\id_ed25519 user1@serverip` still prompts me for a password. Any ideas?